# SOCKADDR_INET in golang

Tags: go, cgo

I have a byte array that is actually filled with SOCKADDR_INET structures by C++ function in the kernel, after transfer to user mode I need to marshal it in the slice of SOCKADDR_INET equivalent. The syscall package contains sockaddr_in and sockaddr_in6 but as I see golang has a lack of a union to emulate SOCKADDR_INET. I'm new in golang so wondering about the right solution for this case.

Comment: In Go, it's done differently: it operates with [`net.IP`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#IP) which is a byte slice which contents is interpreted based on the context a particular value is used in.

Comment: but it contains only info about address, I need to store remote port too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `si_family` field at the end identifies if the bytes should be interpreted as IPv4 or IPv6 SOCKADDR structure.

The most easy route is likey to make a function to unmarshall the bytes into a go version of the `SOCKADDR_IN` or `SOCKADDR_IN6` struct depending on the value of `si_family`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and what if I don't want to care about si_family and store both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses in the container (slice) ?